# Expires directive - modification base VS Access base

Tags: apache, .htaccess, browser-cache, mod-expires

From what I know this:

```
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 30 days"
```

will make the browser cache request for fresh content after storing the content die 30 days.

But with:

```
ExpiresByType text/html "modification plus 30 days"
```

the browser cache will know with the help of LAST MODIFIED HEADER not to request for fresh content until 30 days of modification.

So my question is, **why not use Modification Base all the time as it seems to make better sense or is there something I am missing?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [apache mod_expires docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_expires.html) say this:

> The difference in effect is subtle. If **M** is used, all current copies of the document in all caches will expire at the same time, which can be good for something like a weekly notice that's always found at the same URL. If **A** is used, the date of expiration is different for each client; this can be good for image files that don't change very often, particularly for a set of related documents that all refer to the same images (i.e., the images will be accessed repeatedly within a relatively short timespan).

Where **M** is the *modification plus* and **A** is the *access plus*. So it looks like it's a matter of how you want to cache to work across all browsers. Do you want your resource to have its cache expire *across all browsers all at the same time*? Or do you want your resource to have its cache expiry *staggered across all browsers*? In particular, it comes down to the type of resource that's being cached here.

If I have a page for example, `/live_shows.html` that doesn't ever change except once a week, where I only ever update it at the beginning of the week to list all the live shows I'll have in my bar, then I'm going to want to use `"modification plus 7 days"`. Because it's every 7 days that it'll be updated, no more, no less.

If I have a directory of images that are displayed on the `/live_shows.html` page, but rarely ever do they get changed because they're like icons and banners and bullets, I use them all the time. Then I'm going to want to make them `"access plus 30 days"` because it's not really that important to get updates for these changes, if there are ever any changes.